# Ext JS 5 Data Binding Combobox

Tags: extjs, mvvm, binding, extjs5

I have an Ext JS 5.0.1 application that I am working on. I have a simple window with a grid and a form. I have the grid bound to my store and when a row is selected, all the textfields in the form bind, but I also have a combobox with its own store. When I select the grid row, I could not get the combobox to bind. I finally figured that out, but now if you change the combobox on the form the grid column just shows object.object. I have created a fiddle if anybody can help me out a little with this problem. Obviously I am trying to use the MVVM but also I would like for it to work in Architect if possible.
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ob5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `value`, not `selection`:

```
value: '{allPeople.selection.gender}'
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/obm

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. Still trying to wrap my head around binding. This is very helpful.